# How to supply configuration file to JobDSL test?

Tags: maven, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I've been tearing my hair out trying to get this to work after the Job DSL plugin deprecated and dropped support for some older ConfigFile classes.  I have Jenkins jobs that use the Config File Provider plugin to get Maven settings.  Unfortunately, my unit test fails with

```
MavenSettings config file with name 'my-maven-settings' not found.
```

The part of my test that is trying create that file is here:

```
    given:
    JobManagement jm = new JenkinsJobManagement(System.out, [:], new File('.'))

    ConfigProvider cfgProvider = jenkinsRule.getInstance().getExtensionList(MavenSettingsConfig.MavenSettingsConfigProvider.class).get(MavenSettingsConfig.MavenSettingsConfigProvider.class)
    Config siteCfg = cfgProvider.newConfig("${Projects.siteAbbr}-mvn-settings","${Projects.mavenSettingsName}",null,null)

    GlobalConfigFiles.get().save(siteCfg)


    when:
    new DslScriptLoader(jm).runScript(file.text)

    then:
    noExceptionThrown()

    where:
    file << jobFiles
```

That code doesn't seem to cause any issues for the Groovy compiler but it doesn't seem to be providing what my job is expecting to see either.  Any idea how to create config files when unit testing a Job DSL script?

Comment: Hey I'm trying do the exactly same. But I have no idea how/where to start. Very new to Jenksin Jobs DSL can you point me to some github examples? or provide some details on where you making all these changes?

Answer (score 0):

Update to Job DSL 1.65 or later. In that version the check has been removed and any config file ID is accepted. So you do not need to create or mock any config files when testing scripts.